# How generate processed features (on which the model was trained) from raw features?

Tags: python, tflite

I am building a project to classify different types of vibrations using edge impulse studio. I collected data from my sensor and trained the model and downloaded its .tflite file from the dashboard:

tflite file from edge impulse

[image]

To load the model into my python program I have used the following code:

```
# Load TFLite model interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path = "/content/ei-testing-nn-classifier-tensorflow-lite-float32-model.lite") 

# Get input and output tensors. 
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details() 
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()

# Allocate tensors 
interpreter.allocate_tensors()
```

After this I have to provide an array of features to my model that it will be classifying. For this I have used:

```
features = [
    # paste processed features from edge impulse studio here
]

# convert features to numpy array of expected data type
np_features = np.array(features)
input_type = input_details[0]['dtype']
np_features = np_features.astype(input_type)

# Add dimension to input sample (TFLite model expects (# samples, data))
np_features = np.expand_dims(np_features, axis=0)

# input_data = np.array(np_features, dtype=np.float32)
interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], np_features)

interpreter.invoke()

# Classifying
output_data = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])
output_data
```

In the features list on line 1, I can not pass the raw features that my sensor has collected as the inference expects processed features on which the model was trained.

So for this I have acquired raw data from my sensor, sent it to edge impulse studio and from there I copied the processed features generated from it:

processed features from edge impulse

[image]

And pasted them in my features array:

```
features = [0.1992, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.1992, 0.0586, 0.0000, 0.0586, 0.3477, 0.3477, 0.3086, 0.3086, 0.3516, 0.3516, 0.2031, 0.2031, 0.3516, 0.2773, 0.1758, 0.2969, 0.2813, 0.2070, 0.1992, 0.2852, 0.4375, 0.4180, 0.4102, 0.5703, 0.5742, 0.4375, 0.4805, 0.4922, 0.4570, 0.4609, 0.4023, 0.4063, 0.4336, 0.3906, 0.4102, 0.3906, 0.4609, 0.1875, ... ]
```

But this is inefficient, and I want a method to convert the **raw features** from my sensor into **processed features** (on which my model is trained), within my python program.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the Python code for the data processing here: https://github.com/edgeimpulse/processing-blocks - pass your raw data through the respective block and then call TFLite.

Alternatively (and preferably) on Linux and macOS use [Edge Impulse for Linux' Python SDK](https://docs.edgeimpulse.com/docs/edge-impulse-for-linux/linux-python-sdk). That actually does both the pre-processing, inference and post-processing in one go.